# Error while installing cloud_firestore in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.

  > Android dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.1.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Comment: Looks like a duplicate to this questions : [dependency 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime' has different version for classpath in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931266/dependency-android-arch-lifecycleruntime-has-different-version-for-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to android\build.gradle inside buildscript{...}

```
subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.0.0"
            }
            if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                details.useVersion "1.0.1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```